# Sending an int over TCP (C-programming)

Tags: c, macos, tcp, sockets, integer

I have a server and a client program (both running on the same machine). The client is able to send a struct to the server with members such as "ID", "size" etc. Then I would like the server to send the ID-member (just an integer) back to the client as an ACK for validation, but I just can't figure this out despite being able to send the struct without problems..

Here is the code from server.c:

```
/* having just recieved the struct */

int ACK_ID = struct_buffer->message_ID;
result = send(CLIENT_socket, &ACK_ID, sizeof(int), 0);

if (result == -1) {
    close(SERVER_socket);
    printf("\n\t[ERROR] Failed to send ACK.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is the code from client.c:

```
// Recieve ACK from server
int ACK_ID;
com_result = read(CLIENT_socket, &ACK_ID, sizeof(int), 0);

if ((com_result == -1) || (ACK_ID != metablocks[index].message_ID)) {
    printf("\n\t[ERROR] Failed to send metadata. ACK: %i\n", ACK_ID);
}
```

When I try to run this I get the following output from client.c:

> [ERROR] Failed to send metadata. ACK: 14

And of course the server tells me it failed to send ACK. The value of the ID integer I'm trying to send should be 1, but it is recieved as 14. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**
So I just tried what Mr. Shawley suggested, and got this error message:

> Partial read: Undefined error: 0

First I tried exactly what he wrote, but then I noticed that the code is comparing `com_result` with `sizeof(int)`. So I assumed that was a typo and tried replacing `com_result` with the `ACK_ID` variable in the comparison. Same result.

**Update 2**
Just added a perror() on the server when it fails, and got the following error message:

> Bad file descriptor

I am using the same socket for this operation as the one I used when receiving the struct. Here is an expanded code sample from server.c:

```
// Recieve connection
CLIENT_socket = accept(SERVER_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&CLIENT_address, &CLIENT_address_length);
if (CLIENT_socket == -1) {
    close(SERVER_socket);
    printf("\n\t[ERROR] Failed to accept client connection.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("\n\tClient connected!\n");

int data_size;

// Read meta data from connection
data_size = sizeof(struct msg_meta);
result = read(CLIENT_socket, &meta_buffer_char, data_size, 0);
meta_buffer = (struct msg_meta *) meta_buffer_char;

if (result == -1) {
    close(SERVER_socket);
    printf("\n\t[ERROR] Failed to read from connection.\n");
    perror("\n\tRead");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else if (result > 0) {
    printf("\n\tMessage recieved.\n");
    printf("\n");
}

// Send ACK back to client
int ACK_ID = meta_buffer->message_ID;
result = send(CLIENT_socket, &ACK_ID, sizeof(int), 0);

if (result == -1) {
    printf("\n\t[ERROR] Failed to send ACK.");
    perror("\n\tSend");
    printf("\n");
    close(SERVER_socket);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Close sockets
close(SERVER_socket);
close(CLIENT_socket);
```

Comment: Aside: use `htonl` and `ntohl` when sending and receiving (respectively) an int to ensure it has the correct byte order.

Comment: Can't say for sure until you print the network errors, if any.  You might as well also verify that the original struct sent to the server actually contains the values you expect.

Comment: @outis: nah, look at the same person's question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734819/sending-struct-over-tcp-c-programming. He knows he's in a state of sin with respect to portability. There's nothing wrong with defining a wire protocol with little-endian integers, he'll just have to change it (or start byte-swapping) if he ever wants big-endian clients or servers.

Comment: The struct is validated on the server. I know I'm sending the right data back to the client..

Comment: Mr Shawley assumes your send succeeds, but your question says *the server tells me it failed to send ACK*  Try `perror` on the server side as well.  (Btw, a partial read is rather strange if the server fails to send the ACK!)

Comment: Capitol idea:) Just tried that.. updating post

Comment: @Andomar - It isn't a partial read, the server is sending FIN.

Comment: It does sound like a `FIN`. The server side closing the socket will result in receiving zero bytes on the client side. I knew that there was a reason that I wrapped all of my TCP code in a library so long ago ;)

Comment: 1) Why does your read take four arguments? I am used to only using three.

2) 0 is a valid return value from read(), you should check for 0.

Comment: @Duck: Right!  @Eirik Lillebo: call `perror` as the FIRST THING.  If you call it after `close` or `printf`, it'll report that the `printf` was successful.

Comment: I tried that. Same result... Growing desperate here.

Comment: @Eirik - It's impossible to tell from what we have seen so far.  I would suggest posting the smallest possible amount of *working* code that exhibits the problem.  This is pretty confusing at this point so post a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: update 2 - Make sure you are (a) using the correct file descriptor and (b) didn't close() or shutdown() the write portion of the socket.

Comment: Not completely sure what the problem was, but I'm guessing it had to be something I did wrong in closing the sockets. Have rewritten it now, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the error that is being generated by the send.  You should include the error library `#include <cerrno>` and then check the value of the global `errno`.  There are a variety of macros that declare what type of error occurred.  That will give you more information in debugging exactly why it failed to send the ACK.

Here's a list of the possible error values return (the error values are macros defined in `cerrno`), taken from [here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/send.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/send):

```
     [EACCES]           The SO_BROADCAST option is not set on the socket and a broadcast address is given as
                        the destination.

     [EAGAIN]           The socket is marked non-blocking and the requested operation would block.

     [EBADF]            An invalid descriptor is specified.

     [ECONNRESET]       A connection is forcibly closed by a peer.

     [EFAULT]           An invalid user space address is specified for a parameter.

     [EHOSTUNREACH]     The destination address specifies an unreachable host.

     [EINTR]            A signal interrupts the system call before any data is transmitted.

     [EMSGSIZE]         The socket requires that message be sent atomically, and the size of the message to
                        be sent makes this impossible.  IOV_MAX.

     [ENETDOWN]         The local network interface used to reach the destination is down.

     [ENETUNREACH]      No route to the network is present.

     [ENOBUFS]          The system is unable to allocate an internal buffer.  The operation may succeed when
                        buffers become available.

     [ENOBUFS]          The output queue for a network interface is full.  This generally indicates that the
                        interface has stopped sending, but may be caused by transient congestion.

     [ENOTSOCK]         The argument socket is not a socket.

     [EOPNOTSUPP]       socket does not support (some of) the option(s) specified in flags.

     [EPIPE]            The socket is shut down for writing or the socket is connection-mode and is no
                        longer connected.  In the latter case, and if the socket is of type SOCK_STREAM, the
                        SIGPIPE signal is generated to the calling thread.

     The sendmsg() and sendto() system calls will fail if:

     [EAFNOSUPPORT]     Addresses in the specified address family cannot be used with this socket.

     [EDESTADDRREQ]     The socket is not connection-mode and does not have its peer address set, and no
                        destination address is specified.

     [EISCONN]          A destination address was specified and the socket is already connected.

     [ENOENT]           A component of the pathname does not name an existing file or the path name is an
                        empty string.

     [ENOMEM]           Insufficient memory is available to fulfill the request.

     [ENOTCONN]         The socket is connection-mode, but is not connected.

     [ENOTDIR]          A component of the path prefix of the pathname in the socket address is not a direc-tory. directory.
                        tory.

     The send() system call will fail if:

     [EDESTADDRREQ]     The socket is not connection-mode and no peer address is set.

     [ENOTCONN]         The socket is not connected or otherwise has not had the peer pre-specified.

     The sendmsg() system call will fail if:

     [EINVAL]           The sum of the iov_len values overflows an ssize_t.

     [EMSGSIZE]         The socket requires that message be sent atomically, and the size of the message to
                        be sent makes this impossible, or the msg_iovlen member of the msghdr structure
                        pointed to by message is less than or equal to  or is greater than IOV_MAX.
```

Comment: None that I can spot.  But no error flag is rather strange.  I'm as clueless as you are at this point.  I'll keep looking at it...

Comment: I mean, aside from the previously mentioned need to convert your integers to network byte ordering and back again.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal source code which exhibits this problem?

Comment: (A complete minimal test program I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `read` is failing resulting in `com_result == -1`.  In this case, the value of `ACK_ID` is undefined stack garbage.  Try this instead:

```
com_result = read(CLIENT_socket, &ACK_ID, sizeof(int), 0);
if (com_result < 0) {
    perror("read");
} else if (com_result != sizeof(int)) {
    /* handle partial read condition */
} else if (ACK_ID != metablocks[index].message_ID) {
    printf("\n\t[ERROR] Failed to receive metadata. ACK: %i\n", ACK_ID);
}
```

There are a number of reasons that `read()` might fail or return a partial result - this is TCP after all.  [`Perror`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/perror.html) will essentially call [`strerror(errno)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/strerror.html) for you and display the message that you supply with the error string appended to it.  When a system call like `read()` or `send()` returns -1, it sets `errno` to a more descriptive value that you can display using `perror()` or `strerror()`.

### Update - Partial Reads

As for the partial read problem, you usually solve this by either (1) ignoring it or (2) doing the read in a loop until you get all of the bytes that you are expecting.  Something like:

```
int status = 0;
char *byte_ptr = (char*)&ACK_ID;
ssize_t bytes_left = sizeof(ACK_ID);
while (bytes_left > 0) {
   ssize_t rc = read(CLIENT_socket, byte_ptr, bytes_left);
   if (rc < 0) {
       if (errno == EINTR) {
           continue; /* interrupted system call */
       }
       perror("read");
       status = -1;
       break;
   } else if (rc == 0) {
       /* EOF */
       break;
   }
   bytes_left -= rc;
   byte_ptr += rc;
}
if (status == 0) {
    if (bytes_left == 0) {
        /* safely use the value stored in ACK_ID */
    } else {
        /* handle premature socket closure */
    }
}
```

Usually this is wrapped in a common library function to make life easier.  I would recommend reading [W. Richard Steven's UNIX Network Programming, volume 1](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html) if you haven't already.  This is exactly what he does in his `readn()` library function.

Comment: Partial read will not set errno, using perror there is fairly fruitless

Answer (score 0):

You could check why the `send` is failing.  For example, use [`perror`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/perror.html):

```
if (result == -1) {
    perror("server error while sending ack");
    ....
```

Be sure not to call any other function between the failed `send` and `perror`, as that would reset `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

First, try using htonl before sending the int, and using ntohl after receiving it.
Then, you should ALWAYS send and recv in loops, so you send and recv the WHOLE length of your data.