# SENDING STRUCTS using tcp sockets

Tags: file, tcp, endianness, struct

I am reading a file to the structs, then write them to the server.
Here is a snippet of code:

```
struct b{
uint16_t num;
char str[10];
} x;
 struct a{
 uint32_t pid;
 char str1[10];
 char str2[10];
```

} y;

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s",buff) != EOF)
while(1){
c = getchar();
if (c == '\n')
break;

else
buff[i]= c ;
i++;

write(fd, &b,sizeof(b))
```

> Text File Format

- 123
- George
- Lee
- How do I read and store the file to each struct?
- When I write to a server, does it look like
- write(fd, &a,sizeof(struct a)).
  write(fd,&b,sizeof(struct b))?
  How to ensure correct padding, endianness

This is how I run the file : /a.out IP PORT < file.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending struct over TCP (C-programming)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734819/sending-struct-over-tcp-c-programming)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking new questions, please use the search. Many questions have already been asked on SO and you may find your answer instantly.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "read and store the file to each struct", could you clarify that question?

To ensure the right padding and endian-ness, you have to do two things:

1. Send the struct one field at a time. It is a pain. Since you are declaring each struct member as a `uint16_t` type (and from that family), sizeof() will give you the same answer across all platforms.
2. TO ensure endianness, you have to use the host-to-network-order family. See: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Byte-Order.html
3. When you do this, you have to use `htons()` (host to network short) when sending and then `ntohs()` (network to host short) when receiving. For each member of your struct.

Often people ignore this; if both machines are modern Intel boxes, which is true for the vast majority of us, you can get away with the code you have for sending structs. But like you have mentioned, that doesn't gaurantee padding and endinaness!

You could also use the [#pragma pack()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) GNU directives for specifying how padding should be handled. This works if you can rely on the GNU toolchain for both your client and server, as that is not part of the C specification.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use send/recv (sockets) or read/write (file descriptors) with structures. It's virtually guaranteed to break later on. Among other problems, the padding and/or alignment of the structure members can change depending on the compiler, the compilation options, and the environment.

Instead, marshal the data into an independent format (like text) and send that. If the data must be absolutely the same on both sides, encode it into base 64 and prepend a checksum.

If you absolutely must transmit binary data, remember to convert each of the structure members to network byte order (`man byteorder`) and send each one individually.